# Making a Div height adjust relative to a second adsolute positioned div

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am trying to make a website that will scale the height of the content div based on the the divs nested within using the following setup:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="col1">content</div>
    <div id="col2">content</div>
</div>
```

with the CSS being set:

```
#content {
height:auto
position: relative;
}

#col1 {
width: 30%px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

#col2 {
width: 68%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

the problem however is that with the content height set to auto the div collapses instead of adjusting its height to fit the longer of the two columns (#col2)

Is the only way of preventing the div collapsing in on itself manually coding a height instead of auto or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned divs are taken out of the flow, so you will not be able to accomplish this with the CSS you are using.

Instead, if possible, you can use floats:

```
#content {
    height:auto;
    width:300px; /* some width */
    float:left;
}

#col1 {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;    
}

#col2 {
    width: 70%;
    float:right;
}
```

Edit: See example with your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using absolute position on the right hand column putting it both top and bottom, then it will grow when the outside relative container grows - which will auto grow with the left hand colum: http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/4/

```
#content {
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}

#col1 {
    width: 30%;
    background:#ff0000;
}

#col2 {
    width: 70%;    
    background:#000fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but you have to be sure the right column always has less content then the left one, since the left one won't stretch along with the absolute positioned column.